# sum only values in a column with not null values in other columns in a table using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Table Prod

```
  Product  quantity    Weight 
    A        10          2
    B        20          3
    C        30          0
    D        40          0

select SUM((quantity*weight)) / sum(NULLIF(quantity,0) ) As [Tot Avg]
from prod
```

Expected Output:

```
80/30 = 2.67
```

But above query will output

```
80/100 = 0.8
```

How to achieve the 2.67 result?
I want to sum(quantity) with not null weight column values.

Comment: `SUM((quantity*weight)) / sum(CASE WHEN weight = 0 THEN 0 ELSE quantity)`

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
    select SUM((quantity*weight)) / sum(coalesce(1.0*( case when weight > 0 then quantity else 0 end),0)) As [Tot Avg]
from prod
```

The output is:

```
Tot Avg
2.67
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally misunderstood the question.

Simply use a `where` clause:
However, I would simplify it to:

```
select sum(quantity * weight) * 1.0 / nullif(sum(quantity), 0) As TotAvg
from prod
where weight <> 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eff2da98aa1643bf6d3f07d8502711c5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks but i want to add quantity values only whose weight is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
declare @wq int

set @wq=(select SUM((quantity*weight)) from Product)

declare @quantity int

set @quantity=(select SUM(quantity)from Product where Weight<>0 )

select CAST(@wq AS float)/CAST(@quantity AS float)
```